# python3 opencv not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I installed opencv on my ubuntu 20.04 :

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (4.6.0.66)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in /home/alexandre/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.22.1)
```

and when I run my code : python3 schli.py

I get :   NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined

my code :

```
import cv2 as cv

bruitelect = cv.imread("bruit-electro.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
brut = cv.imread("17-14-05.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
fond = cv.imread("bruit-fond.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv.imshow('grayscale image', brut)

"""
"image brut - bruit elec"
num = cv.absdiff(brut,bruitelec)

"image fond - bruit elec"
deno = cv.absdiff(fond,bruitelec)

schlie = num/deno
"""
```

I don't understand why ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `opencv` as:

```
import cv2 as cv
```

While you are using `cv2` in the following lines:

```
bruitelect = cv.imread("bruit-electro.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
brut = cv.imread("17-14-05.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
fond = cv.imread("bruit-fond.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

You need to replace the above lines with the following:

```
bruitelect = cv.imread("bruit-electro.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
brut = cv.imread("17-14-05.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
fond = cv.imread("bruit-fond.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```